# Python how to double a function after its been execued, using autopygui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import pyautogui
var = 1
time.sleep(1)
while var < 90:
    var = var + 1
    pyautogui.press('>')
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

I need to make it type

```
>
>>
>>>
>>>>
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [typewrite()](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html):

```
import time
import pyautogui
var = 1
charr = '>'
time.sleep(1)
while var < 90:
    pyautogui.typewrite(charr)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    charr += '>'
    var += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>
>>
>>>
>>>>
```